# Reading out a table in C# with HtmlAgilityPack

Tags: c#, html, html-agility-pack

I have been trying for quite a while but this is my case;

My friend's web application runs a website with quite simple HTML to generate data for charts. I want to get certain values from a table on that page as he requires this information to be stored to a database.

So this is a part of the HTML table;

```
...
<tr>
    <td width=30 align=center bgcolor=#006699 class=W><font color=white>1</font></td>
    <td width=50 bgcolor=#FFFFFF align=center>7387</td>

    <td width=30 height=25 align=center bgcolor=#006699 class=W><font color=white>2</font></td>
    <td width=50 bgcolor=#FFFFFF align=center>2881</td>

    <td width=30 height=25 align=center bgcolor=#006699 class=W><font color=white>3</font></td>
    <td width=50 bgcolor=#FFFFFF align=center>8782</td>

    <td width=30 height=25 align=center bgcolor=#006699 class=W><font color=white>4</font></td>
    <td width=50 bgcolor=#FFFFFF align=center>5297</td>

    <td width=30 height=25 align=center bgcolor=#006699 class=W><font color=white>5</font></td>
    <td width=50 bgcolor=#FFFFFF align=center>749</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td align=center bgcolor=#006699 class=W><font color=white>6</font></td>
    <td width=50 bgcolor=#FFFFFF align=center>3136</td>

    <td height=25 align=center bgcolor=#006699 class=W><font color=white>7</font></td>
    <td width=50 bgcolor=#FFFFFF align=center>8768</td>

    <td height=25 align=center bgcolor=#006699 class=W><font color=white>8</font></td>
    <td width=50 bgcolor=#FFFFFF align=center>9548</td>

    <td height=25 align=center bgcolor=#006699 class=W><font color=white>9</font></td>
    <td width=50 bgcolor=#FFFFFF align=center>6565</td>

    <td height=25 align=center bgcolor=#006699 class=W><font color=white>10</font></td>
    <td width=50 bgcolor=#FFFFFF align=center>142</td>
</tr>
...
```

What I want to achieve is;

- I get two numbers - for example 1 and 8.
- My application checks the HTML of the page and selects the two `td` (as shown above) containing the numbers.
- Then, I have to get the value of the NEXT `td`.

The output of this would be `1=7387` and `8=9548`.
I got stuck quite fast after trying to find the two `td` containing the given numbers.

My C# code so far;

```
using (WebClient webClient = new WebClient())
{
    string completeHTMLCode = webClient.DownloadString("someUrl.php?getChartData=" + chartId);

    HtmlDocument doc = new HtmlDocument();
    doc.LoadHtml(completeHTMLCode);

    foreach (HtmlNode link in doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//td[@...]"))
    {

    }
 }
```

Am I trying something impossible here?

Comment: Was adding it. Sorry.

Comment: That HTML is quite horrible but I think what you are trying sounds really easy actually. I would try using CSQuery for this though (it might choke on the quite nasty HTML in your input though).

Comment: I wish I had control over the HTML. This is indeed horrible and you'd get a shock if you saw the whole document. I will take a look at CSQuery.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I made a quick CsQuery sample how to accomplish this.

```
string file = File.ReadAllText("a.html"); // gets the html

CQ dom = file; // initializes csquery
CQ td = dom["td"]; // get all td files

td.Each((i,e) => { // go through each
    if (e.FirstChild != null) // if element has child (font)
    {
        if (e.FirstChild.NodeType != NodeType.TEXT_NODE) // ignore text node
        {
            if (e.FirstChild.InnerText == "1") // if number is 1
            {
                Console.WriteLine(e.NextElementSibling.InnerText); // output the text
            }
            if (e.FirstChild.InnerText == "8") // etc etc
            {
                Console.WriteLine(e.NextElementSibling.InnerText);
            }
        }
    }

});

Console.ReadKey();
```

Comment: CSQuery looks like an interesting alternative to HTMLAgilityPack. I will be investigating it. Thanks for the suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

You can just parse it into a dictionary and look it up that way. I could think of perhaps some better ways to parse it, but this does what you want.

```
    void Main()
{
    string html = @"<tr>
    <td width=30 align=center bgcolor=#006699 class=W><font color=white>1</font></td>
    <td width=50 bgcolor=#FFFFFF align=center>7387</td>

    <td width=30 height=25 align=center bgcolor=#006699 class=W><font color=white>2</font></td>
    <td width=50 bgcolor=#FFFFFF align=center>2881</td>

    <td width=30 height=25 align=center bgcolor=#006699 class=W><font color=white>3</font></td>
    <td width=50 bgcolor=#FFFFFF align=center>8782</td>

    <td width=30 height=25 align=center bgcolor=#006699 class=W><font color=white>4</font></td>
    <td width=50 bgcolor=#FFFFFF align=center>5297</td>

    <td width=30 height=25 align=center bgcolor=#006699 class=W><font color=white>5</font></td>
    <td width=50 bgcolor=#FFFFFF align=center>749</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td align=center bgcolor=#006699 class=W><font color=white>6</font></td>
    <td width=50 bgcolor=#FFFFFF align=center>3136</td>

    <td height=25 align=center bgcolor=#006699 class=W><font color=white>7</font></td>
    <td width=50 bgcolor=#FFFFFF align=center>8768</td>

    <td height=25 align=center bgcolor=#006699 class=W><font color=white>8</font></td>
    <td width=50 bgcolor=#FFFFFF align=center>9548</td>

    <td height=25 align=center bgcolor=#006699 class=W><font color=white>9</font></td>
    <td width=50 bgcolor=#FFFFFF align=center>6565</td>

    <td height=25 align=center bgcolor=#006699 class=W><font color=white>10</font></td>
    <td width=50 bgcolor=#FFFFFF align=center>142</td>
</tr>";

    HtmlDocument doc = new HtmlDocument();
    doc.LoadHtml(html);

    int[] nodes = doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//td").Select ( dn =>
        int.Parse(dn.InnerHtml.Contains("font") ? dn.FirstChild.InnerHtml : dn.InnerHtml)
        ).ToArray();

    Dictionary<int,int> d = new Dictionary<int,int>();
    for (int i = 0; i < nodes.Length; i+=2)
        d.Add(nodes[i],nodes[i+1]);

    d.Dump();
    d[1].Dump();
    d[8].Dump();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, if you only had this table data to work with it could be parsed using HTMLAgilityPack.

The first thing I'd do is do away with foreach to iterate through the tds, I'd use a counter, then use the counter id as an indexer. The code could look like this

```
for(int i = 1;i <= selectednodes.Count();i++)
{
  if(selectednodes[i-1].InnerHtml.Contains("font")
  {
   if(selectednodes[i-1].FirstChild.Value == "1" || selectednodes[i-1].FirstChild.Value == "8")
   {
      myNodecollection.Add(selectednodes[i])
   }
  }
}
```